How to Migrate from GoogleSignInClient to Credential Manager for User Authentication in Android?
I'm currently updating my Android app to migrate from GoogleSignInClient to the new Credential Manager for user authentication. Previously, I used GoogleSignInClient to get the user's display name, email address, profile photo, and Google ID(Important). Here's a snippet of the old code that was working fine:
  GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

 private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult();
            if (account != null) {
               photoUrl = account.getPhotoUrl();
               name = account.getDisplayName(); 
               email = account.getEmail();
               googleId = account.getId();// <= crucial for my app's functionality
            } 
     }


Now that GoogleSignInClient is deprecated, I'm trying to use Credential Manager instead. However, I'm having trouble finding a direct replacement for the above functionality.
My Questions:

How can I retrieve the user's email address, display name, profile photo, and Google ID using Credential Manager?
Do I need to add any scopes in the OAuth consent screen? With my previous setup, it was working fine without any additional scopes.

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answering my own question. Actually, we can get the google user ID from the token itself.
idToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken
String[] segments = idToken.split("\\.");
byte[] payloadAsByteArray = Base64.decode(segments[1], Base64.NO_PADDING);
JSONObject payloadInJson = new JSONObject(new String(payloadAsByteArray, UTF_8));
String uniqueIdentifier = payloadInJson.get("sub");


As per google new guidelines GoogleSignInClient is depreciated.

Try below code:
try {
    CredentialManager manager = CredentialManager.create(MyActivity.this);
    GetCredentialRequest request = new GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
            .addCredentialOption(new GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
                    .setServerClientId(YOUR_WEB_CLIENT_ID)
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                    .build())
            .build();

    PasswordCredential credential = (PasswordCredential) manager.getCredential(MyActivity.this, request);
    if (credential != null) {
        return credential.getPassword(); // this field holds the Google ID
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle exception
}


Note:
Java doesn't support the coroutines like Kotlin so use AsyncTask class for asynchronous operations. But AsyncTask has been Deprecated in android API level 30 so you may use other concurrency libraries such as ExecutorService, RxJava or Kotlin Coroutines can be considered too in Java.
Reference links

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/credentials/CredentialManager

https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager

Credential Manager - How do I create a "SignInWithGoogle" credential?


Update 1 :
In reference of

cannot cast to PasswordCredential

Before casting, verify the retrieved credential's actual type using instanceof PasswordCredential and handle other credential types in else condition. Also when requesting a credential from CredentialManager, use GetCredentialRequest.Builder to specify the desired credential type.
Take the below example :
val request: GetCredentialRequest = Builder()
  .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
  .build()

coroutineScope.launch {
  try {
    val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
      request = request,
      context = activityContext,
    )
    handleSignIn(result)
  } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
    handleFailure(e)
  }
}

fun handleSignIn(result: GetCredentialResponse) {
  // Handle the successfully returned credential.
  val credential = result.credential

  when (credential) {

    // Passkey credential
    is PublicKeyCredential -> {
      // Share responseJson such as a GetCredentialResponse on your server to
      // validate and authenticate
      responseJson = credential.authenticationResponseJson
    }

    // Password credential
    is PasswordCredential -> {
      // Send ID and password to your server to validate and authenticate.
      val username = credential.id
      val password = credential.password
    }

    // GoogleIdToken credential ---> This is what you requested
    is CustomCredential -> {
      if (credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
        try {
          // Use googleIdTokenCredential and extract id to validate and
          // authenticate on your server.
          val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
            .createFrom(credential.data)
        } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Received an invalid google id token response", e)
        }
      } else {
        // Catch any unrecognized custom credential type here.
        Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential")
      }
    }

    else -> {
      // Catch any unrecognized credential type here.
      Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential")
    }
  }
}

Read this post for more information.

credential.getPassword(); doesn't work

Doesn't work means are you getting null or getPassword gives wrong value?

manager.getCredential(MyActivity.this, request) cannot cast to PasswordCredential

Thank you for the update. I'm already using the code from your updated answer, which successfully returns the email address, name, profile picture URI, and other details. However, it doesn't provide the unique ID of the Google account, which is a crucial requirement for my app.

Check the logcat and tell what you are getting there?
